# tizk: can't link to previous cell in tizk matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

For the fun I wanted to try to build fancy CV in tikz like this one https://fr.freepik.com/vecteurs-libre/modele-cv-minimaliste_13163860.htm#query=cv&position=0&from_view=keyword and I'd need to draw lines between nodes in cells of a tikz matrix.

For that I used `append after command` to add a node and link this node to the rode in the previous cell… unfortunately the link appears in the wrong place (the horizontal lenght is good but it does not go up as expected). I guess that the matrix does not yet know the position of the other cells whenbuilding a new cell…

Any idea how to fix it?

MWE (sorry for the poor indentation, I'm on my phone)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, 
cventry/.style={
  prefix after command={
   [very thick]
            (\tikzlastnode.north west)node[circle,fill=black,minimum width=1mm](mydot-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn){}
}},
linkprevious/.style={
append after command={
(mydot-\the\numexpr\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow - 1\relax-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn) edge[->,red](mydot-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)
}
},
]
       \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&, column sep = 1.5cm, row sep = 1.2cm]{
        |[cventry]| Hello my dear something is strange\\
        |[cventry,linkprevious]| Oui \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When PGF builds the matrix it doesn't yet know where its content will finally lie. For this PGF internally keeps track of all nodes that were created in a matrix and adjusts their references when the matrix is finished so that `(<node name>)` works correctly.

Until then, every node only has a reference local to its cell which means using the previous node returns the coordinates in relation to its cell but PGF doesn't take that in account when its drawing the edge *and* it doesn't even know the vertical distance between the cells – again, the row might contain another cell with `\draw (0,0) -- (5,0);` and the vertical distance would be much bigger than at the time your cell with `linkprevious` is created. (You would also need `overlay` on that edge otherwise the line would actually never protrude outside the cell's bounding box, basically the same reason for `overlay` on lines between different TikZ pictures.)

---

You will need to take a page out of TikZ-CD's playbook where the `\arrow` command delays the drawing until after the matrix by feeding a macro that is only executed after the matrix.

### Feeding a macro from the cells

The `\pgfinteval` macro is just an internal wraper for the `\numexpr` stuff, `\pgfutil@g@addto@macro` is PGF's own version of LaTeX's `\g@addto@macro` which appends `#2` to the definition of `#1`. This is basically `etoolbox`' `\gappto` as long as `#1` is a parameterless macro. `\pgfutil@empty` is PGF's own `\@empty`/`\empty`, basically an “empty” macro (`\def\pgfutil@empty{}`) to initialize the list of edges with.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, matrix}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  matrix with linkpreviouses/.style=% initialize
    /utils/exec=\let\tikz@listofedgesforaftermatrix\pgfutil@empty,
    append after command=\tikz@listofedgesforaftermatrix,
    matrix with linkpreviouses/.code=% disable key
  },
  linkprevious/.code={%
    \edef\tikz@temp{%
      (mydot-\pgfinteval{\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1}-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)
      edge[->,red](mydot-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn)}%
    \expandafter\pgfutil@g@addto@macro\expandafter
      \tikz@listofedgesforaftermatrix\expandafter{\tikz@temp}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  cventry/.style={prefix after command={
    (\tikzlastnode.north west) node[
      very thick, circle,fill=black,minimum width=1mm]
      (mydot-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn){}}}]
\matrix (m) [
  matrix of nodes,
  matrix with linkpreviouses,
  ampersand replacement=\&,
  column sep = 1.5cm,
  row sep = 1.2cm]{
|[cventry]| Hello my dear something is strange\\
|[cventry, linkprevious]| Oui \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Smart code after the matrix

You might just use an `append after command` on the matrix itself where you have some code that figures out what to do. (I'm using the `chains` library's `\chainin` here because it's just the laziest way to connect a bunch of nodes, of course you can just build your edges manually.)

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, matrix}
\tikzset{
  matrix with linkpreviouses/.style={
    append after command={
      [start chain=going above, every join/.append style={<-, red}]
      \foreach \ENTRY in {\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow, ..., 1}{
        (mydot-\ENTRY-1) [late options={on chain, every chain in/.try, join}]
      }}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  cventry/.style={prefix after command={
    (\tikzlastnode.north west) node[
      very thick, circle,fill=black,minimum width=1mm]
      (mydot-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn){}}}]
\matrix (m) [
  matrix of nodes,
  matrix with linkpreviouses,
  ampersand replacement=\&,
  column sep = 1.5cm,
  row sep = 1.2cm]{
|[cventry]| Hello my dear something is strange\\
|[cventry]| Oui \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (both cases)

[image]

Comment: I believe it would be easier to just have the black circles in a row of their own to have them vertically aligned but that's a problem for another question …

Comment: Thanks a lot! Regarding your comment I was thinking that anchor left and/or fixed width would be good enough for alignement. PS: minor typo a `{` is missing after `matrix with linkpreviouses/.style`